# Isn't boost::asio fully UNICODE compliant?

Tags: c++, unicode, boost-asio

I am writing a C++ application that is using boost::asio for some http operations. I chose boost::asio assuming it is fully unicode compliant. However, I am unable compile in UNICODE because some part of asio is hardcoded to char.

Case in point:

```
#ifndef TCHAR
    #ifdef _UNICODE
        #define TCHAR wchar_t
    #else
        #define TCHAR char
    #endif
#endif

// The following lines only complile in MBCS and not in UNICODE.
boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<TCHAR> > request;
std::basic_ostream<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR> > requestStream(&request);
```

The **boost::asio::read_until** function accepts char as a delimiter. Am I doing something wrong here? Please note I am new to unicode, never needed it before.

boost::asio::basic_streambuf derives from std::streambuf instead of std::basic_streambuf, so I suspect boost::asio is not really UNICODE compliant.

Comment: `async_read_until` has several overloads taking in different types as the delimiter.  Why does the networking library need to be unicode compliant?  It's responsibility is sending bytes on the wire, if it's unicode and needs to send 2 bytes instead of one, that is the application's (not the library's) responsibility.

Comment: I am using asio for http operation. I may have to download non-English page. That is why I want UNICODE.

Comment: You don't need -- or even want -- boost::asio to use Unicode in order to use it for the HTTP protocol (which also just treats data as a byte stream). Instead, read up on Unicode encodings, and look to libraries like ICU for higher level Unicode processing or conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, boost::asio is not UNICODE compliant.